# Spring Websockets: how to assign messagemappings from code?

Tags: java, spring, spring-websocket

In Spring Websocket implementation, there is usually an example of specifying handlers for websocket communication in a hardcode way, such as in tutorial https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/

```
@Controller
public class GreetingController {
@MessageMapping("/hello")
@SendTo("/topic/greetings")
public Greeting greeting(HelloMessage message) throws Exception {
    Thread.sleep(3000); // simulated delay
    return new Greeting("Hello, " + message.getName() + "!");
  }
}
```

Can I, however, create some classes for handing messages and define their messagemappings at runtime? I feel like having a special set-up code, that matches MessageMappings to handler classes/methods might help to attach controllers to topics that are not hard-coded, but for instance read from a configuration file. This will also allow to enable/disable select message handlers and keep list of handlers in one place.